# How to change user email in firebase and google account in vue.js of the logged user

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have vue application with firebase social authentication and I have implemented google, facebook and twitter loggin in my app.
Now I want to update user email in my vue app.
Please explain how a logged in user can updated his/her email address in both social and firebase account and then re-authenticate.

Comment: sorry for the title its logged in user

Answer (score 1):

To update the email when using the `email` provider you can use this simple code:

```js
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateEmail("user@example.com").then(() => {
  // Update successful
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile). A reauthentication might be required before changing the email.

For the social providers you can't change the email because it comes from the social media provider and the email is the point of identification.

Comment: I think this will only change firebase email, I want to google/facebook/twitter also

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Firebase Docs, I have already done  updating email and pass in firebase...

Comment: You can only change the email in Firebase. You can't change the email of someones social provider.